# Microsoft outlook Mails through Squid Proxy

Tags: outlook, squid

Today I have configured Squid proxy in my office. it is working fine with out any issue. But from that time, my colleagues are unable to send/receive the emails through Microsoft Outlook (2003 & 2007). But they are able to send the mails using Internet explorer ...
Please let me know the sollution to allow the outlook emails through squid proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Squid doesn't proxy SMTP/IMAP/POP/LDAP or whatever else your email clients are using - it supports HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and gopher.

When you installed the squid server, how did you configure the clients to use it?

Comment: In Internet Explorer : Tools --> Internet options ---> Connections ---> Lan settings ----> Use a configured proxy server 

Mozilla ---> Edit ---> Preferences ---> Connections ---> Ipaddress of proxy server

Chrome and so on

Comment: If that's the only change you made to your networking, then squid shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: I know that squid won't proxy smtp/imap/pop/ldap but... How should we handle this problem, then? Nat? Port forwarding? I have a single NIC on my squid server and I'm clueless :(

Comment: For the record, it is possible to get squid to proxy SMTP, but this is disabled by default.  It is also a very bad idea to set it up so it is possible since it can be used very easily to send out spam.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the proxy's firewall settings if it's directly in the way of network traffic entering/exiting the network.